# Reading custom-made files from C++/C# in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I know the binarywriter() - structure of the file created in C# and i want to read/import that file in MATLAB. Unfortunately, i have tried all the available methods (fopen/fread,textscan etc etc) but i am not able to read it.  Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? What happens when you try to read these files? Do you get an error?

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Please look at the comments below. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found decoding a binary file to be relatively slow in Matlab, so you may want to consider just outputting your data as a CSV file from C#, however, this is how I'd go about decoding your file:

```
f = fopen(filename);
data = fread(f,inf,'*uint8');
fclose(f);

data_size = size(data,1);
index = 1;
byte = 1;

while byte < data_size
   decoded_data(index).val1 = typecast(data(byte:byte+1), 'uint16');
   byte = byte + 2;

   decoded_data(index).val2 = typecast(data(byte:byte+3), 'uint32');
   byte = byte + 4;

   decoded_data(index).val3 = typecast(data(byte:byte+7), 'double');
   byte = byte + 8;

   index = index + 1;
end
```

This is completely untested (although I've done something similar in the past) and it's difficult to give much detail without knowing the format of your data.

I've assumed that your file contains more than one data type, however, if it's just an array of a single type you can replace the while loop with:

```
decoded_data = typecast(data, 'double');
```

If you're not used to working with data types in Matlab in can be a bit of a pain (a lot of functions will only work with doubles). So you could just wrap a cast around all the typecasts like so:

```
decoded_data = double(typecast(data, 'double'));
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the updated information in the comments I've come up with the following solution. It assumes that the strings are always a fixed length. I haven't done much error checking, but have thrown an error if the final string isn't found.

```
filename = 'v1.hrv';
f = fopen(filename);
data = fread(f,inf,'*uint8');
fclose(f);

byte = 1;

decoded_data.name = char(data(byte+1:byte+23))';
byte = byte + 25;

decoded_data.version = char(data(byte:byte+14))';
byte = byte + 16;

decoded_data.patient_id = char(data(byte:byte+3))';
byte = byte + 5;

decoded_data.study = char(data(byte:byte+2))';
byte = byte + 4;

decoded_data.gender = char(data(byte));
byte = byte + 2;

decoded_data.string1 = char(data(byte:byte+2))';
byte = byte + 4;

decoded_data.sample_frequency = char(data(byte:byte+2))';
byte = byte + 4;

decoded_data.string2 = char(data(byte:byte+3))';
byte = byte + 4;

decoded_data.data_length = typecast(data(byte:byte+7), 'int64');
byte = byte + 8;

number_of_data_bytes = decoded_data.data_length * 4;
decoded_data.data = typecast(data(byte:byte+number_of_data_bytes-1), 'single');
byte = byte + number_of_data_bytes + 1;

if ~strcmp('Sample finished', char(data(byte:byte+14))')
   error('File not decoded correctly')
end
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your time to answer my question. My problem is that when i try that, ""data = fread(f,inf,'*uint8');"" returns a null value, so data is empty...

Comment: This is the structure:


bw = New BinaryWriter(myStream) 
bw.Write("My company ECG")   // string 
bw.Write("Version 1.0.0.0")   //string
bw.Write("1001") 'String –Patient ID //string 
bw.Write("001") 'String –Study ID //string
bw.Write("1") 'Integer –gender: 0 male,1 female //string
bw.Write("ECG") //string
bw.Write("500") //string
bw.Write("test")  //string
bw.Write(datas_length) //long or int64
For i As Long = 0 To datas_length - 1 
    bw.Write(ChannelData(i))   //float
Next 
bw.Write("Sample finished")   //string
bw.Close()

Comment: No problem. Hopefully we'll get to the bottom of the issue... `fopen` and `fread` are pretty simple and I'm struggling to imagine what's wrong, so maybe it's worth checking the basics? Can you check that the file is being opened correctly (`f` should have a value >= 3)? Can you check that the file you're opening is greater than 0 bytes in size? Do you get any data if you use `data = fread(f);`? If you upload a copy of the binary file to somewhere and I'll give it a go here.

Comment: yes i can read the file but it's not in the order i want it to be. I do something wrong. I try to follow the structure i posted before. the file is here @sclarke81. [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/k5qzzb)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine although it pops an error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in test (line 11)
   decoded_data(index).name = char(data(byte+1:byte+23))';" Due to increment mishandling.   I only want to extract the data that is stored in this hrv file in order to process them. @sclarke81

Comment: Is the `BinaryWriter` code under your control? If so I'd really recommend designing a better binary file format and updating the code. That will then make the decoding easy. I honestly believe your problems are stemming from having a loose binary file format.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to the Visual Basic code as the hardware and software have already been developed. I only need to be able to read the Data of this file, i don't really care for the other fields if that helps. @sclarke81

Comment: Ok, that's fair enough. Do you have any documentation describing the binary file format? What I'm really digging for is whether the strings at the beginning are always a fixed length? Does a file contain a single set of data or multiple sets?

Comment: 1.string   "MedKinetic Inc ECG 2010"  - Productor information
2.string     "Version 1.0.0.0"  -Version information
3.string     "1001"    -Patient ID
4.string    "001"    -Study ID
5.string    "1"    -gender
6.string    "EGG"    
7.string    "500"    -sample frequency
8.string    "test"    
9.long       -data length 
10.float     -sample data array
11.string    "Sample finished"    -finish mark

Comment: The programmer of the .hrv file replied to me as: 1) are the strings at the beginning are always a fixed length? 
Ans: no ,According to the actual length of the string is written. 

2) Does a file contain a single set of data or multiple sets?
Ans: please set one -dimensional arrays to store data.

Comment: And he is willing to change the way the .hrv files are stored if eventually there is a reading problem. @sclarke81

Comment: @GeorgeLaza I updated my answer with a working solution that decodes the file that you posted. You have a choice. 1) Use the present solution and tweak the string lengths for each file that you decode. 2) Adapt the present solution to cope with the variable length strings by searching for a fixed string (e.g. `test`) and using knowledge of that location to find the start of the data. 3) Update the binary file format to be more robust and easier to decode. Depending on what you decide to do you might want to start a new question as this one is drifting away from your original problem.

Comment: i really thank you. I mean it. Much obliged my friend :)

Comment: ok. I will start a new question based on your answer to see what people think is the best choice, as I cannot change the original binary file. @sclarke81